# Display distinct values of a column along with corresponding count

Tags: sql

I want to display distinct values of a column along with no. of occurences of that value. For example:
Values:

```
     a
     b
     a
     c
     d
     a
     b
     c
```

I want to get the output like below:

```
     a 3
     b 2
     c 2
     d 1
```

I am able to get distinct value and no.of occurrences separately but not able to generate the outputs together. I have tried multiple row subqueries but its taking all the values from the sub query from where clause and displaying total count. Can anyone give me the correct syntax to generate the required output. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can do it with `group by` clause:

```
select
    clmn,
    count(clmn) as cnt
from tbl
group by clmn
order by clmn
```

Answer (score 0):

@Prashanth  you can try this:-

```
 SELECT  column_name,count(column_name)as occurence 
 FROM table_name 
 GROUP BY column_name
 ORDER BY column_name
```